# Difference between LoadState and navigationHelper_LoadState

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am new to windows store app development. Currently I am looking into passing and receiving parameter between xamls, using c#.

Can someone help explain difference between `LoadState()` and `navigationHelper_LoadState()` with some examples? Which should I go for receiving parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, NavigationHelper.LoadState requires two things:

1. `OnNavigatedTo` *Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.*
2. `NavigationMode.New` *Navigation is to a new instance of a page (not forward or back)*

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj655410.aspx) says:

> In addition to providing the implementations described earlier, NavigationHelper also needs to be called from the OnNavigatedTo() and OnNavigatedFrom() event handlers that are implemented on each page. When these events occur, NavigationHelper calls a page-specific implementation of LoadState() and SaveState(). You can customize the implementation of these functions on each page. They should be used in place of OnNavigatedTo() and OnNavigatedFrom() respectively.

The raw code is:

```
public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var frameState = SuspensionManager.SessionStateForFrame(this.Frame);
    this._pageKey = "Page-" + this.Frame.BackStackDepth;
    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.New)
    {
        var nextPageKey = this._pageKey;
        int nextPageIndex = this.Frame.BackStackDepth;
        while (frameState.Remove(nextPageKey))
        {
            nextPageIndex++;
            nextPageKey = "Page-" + nextPageIndex;
        }
        if (this.LoadState != null)
        {
            this.LoadState(this, new LoadStateEventArgs(e.Parameter, null));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (this.LoadState != null)
        {
            this.LoadState(this, new LoadStateEventArgs(e.Parameter, (Dictionary<String, Object>)frameState[this._pageKey]));
        }
    }
}
```

For the sake of your question, there is no LoadState() override unless you define your own like [this blog](http://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/10/10/a-base-page-class-for-windows-8-1-store-apps-with-c-and-xaml/). He simply does this:

```
private void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    LoadState(e);
}

private void navigationHelper_SaveState(object sender, SaveStateEventArgs e)
{
    SaveState(e);
}

protected virtual void LoadState(LoadStateEventArgs e) { }
protected virtual void SaveState(SaveStateEventArgs e) { }
```

See, they are identical. Nothing different between them except the execution pipeline which might impact timing a little, but not likely. In the end, no real difference. People who need to use one over the other... they have to be mistaken, attributing a cause where something else is the influence.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of example online. You might be better off going through those and then coming back here for more specific questions.

http://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/10/10/a-base-page-class-for-windows-8-1-store-apps-with-c-and-xaml/

Comment: my question is more or less similar to this, and my code will only worked if I use loadstate instead of navigationHelper_loadstate.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/53c16310-d60c-44ce-abd3-d9f30eac495c/split-app-xaml-selecting-a-different-listview-item-on-page-load?forum=winappswithcsharp